# what is the best way to add a column to a large data set on a csv file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

i have a data (3000 rows and 20000 columns) i need to add a column with a header of 'class' and the all 3000 rows contain the same word which is here 'Big' how i can do that using python? i tried to do it manually but the file is too large for excel it can't be loaded completely.
I know it may seems easy but i'm new to python tried several codes but non of them gave the needed result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Pandas module](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/file.csv').assign(Class='Big')
df.to_csv('/path/to/new_file.csv', index=False)
```

or as a one-liner:

```
pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/file.csv').assign(Class='Big') \ 
  .to_csv(r'/path/to/new_file.csv', index=False)
```

**UPDATE:**

> I have 9 files as the one you just helped me to add a column to, each
>   one represent a class's attributes. can you tell me how i can combine
>   these files in one csv file, that will be 27000 rows and 30000
>   columns?

```
files = ['file1.csv','file2.csv', ...]

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: it gives that error:    df = pd.read_csv('pdc_big copy.csv').assign(class='Big')
                                                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @sara, `class` is a reserved word, so try `Class` instead

Comment: I have 9 files as the one you just helped me to add a column to, each one represent a class's attributes. can you tell me how i can combine these files in one csv file, that will be 27000 rows and 30000 columns?

Comment: it doesn't combine the files the write way. i need the rows of the second to combine under the rows of the first file. for example if i'm combining two files a get a file of shape 6000 rows and 20000 columns.